# Linux Kernel current version ahead of Ubuntu

Tags: kernel

Why is the Ubuntu kernel (4.1.5) so far behind the current Linux Kernel (5.2.6, soon to be 5.3)?

I would love to use Ubuntu, but my development work depends on solid kernel code.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 uses kernel 4.15, which is a long term support (i.e. very stable) version of the Linux kernel. Newer kernels are often unstable. You can use tools like `ukuu` to update the kernel, but that is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm similar to you mate, but I am running 5.2.5 (haven't installed 5.2.6 yet) on Ubuntu.

Ukuu is a great tool for installing up-to-date kernels, can be installed as follows.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Comment: ukuu has moved from freeware to $12, and is no longer available via this PPA.